# Error while installing codelite on Ubuntu 20.04 - cannot initiate connection

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, codelite, ubuntu-20.04

I tried installing Codelite on Ubuntu 20.04 and was following the steps given here https://wiki.codelite.org/pmwiki.php/Main/Repositories#toc1, but it doesn't go beyond the second step and gives the following error :

> Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2403:8940:ffff::f). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (103.97.84.254), connection timed out

> W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'fossa/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'fossa' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

Similar errors follow.

Everytime I use sudo apt-get update, it tries to fetch the same repository and the command doesn't works properly.

Is there anything that can be done so that I can either completely remove these packages/repositories so that the apt command works as desired or get codelite installed?

I am new to the linux environment, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following

```
sudo nano /etc/gai.conf
```

Scroll with arrow keys down to where it says

```
#precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100
```

and remove the comment (#)

Press control+x to save, and you should be on your way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But I figured it out this way: Changing the "download from" option in the "Software and Updates" tool, and setting it to "main server".